# match with int() and bool()

Tags: python, python-3.10

With Python 3.10.2, consider this code snippet.

```
def print_type(v):
    match v:
        case int() as v:
            s = f"int {v}"
        case bool() as v:
            s = f"bool {v}"
        case _:
            s = "other"
    print(s)
```

Try it with 's = False' and it will print 'bool False' as expected. Now reverse the bool() and int() cases and the result will now be 'int False'. Not exactly what I expected.

Is it a bug? If so, I'll post on the Python forum.

**EDIT**

Based on trincot's answer, here is a version of the code that has the expected behavior.

```
def print_type(v):
    match v:
        case int() as v:
            if isinstance(v, bool):
                s = f"bool {v}"
            else:
                s = f"int {v}"
        case _:
            s = "other"
    print(s)
```

Comment: Did you mean "Try it with `v = False`"?

Comment: I think you're describing it the wrong way around?! The example code will print `int False` for `print_type(False)`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. `bool` is a subclass of `int`, and so every boolean is also an integer.

```
print(isinstance(True, int))  # True
```

Comment: You'r right. A basic notion that I should have thought of.